# How to create a game window in microsoft visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying hard to create [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD3-NZzO2Ao) project in C++, but I have no clue how to get this window to work (I get lost at about 16:00). I've got SDL working and all that, but I can't make main.cpp work. Here is my code:

*Graphics.h in header files*

```
    #ifndef GRAPHICS_H
    #define GRAPHICS_H

    struct SDL_Window;
    struct SDL_Renderer;

    class Graphics {
    public:
        Graphics();
        ~Graphics();
    private:
        SDL_Window* _window;
        SDL_Renderer* _renderer;
    }; 

    #endif
```

*Graphics.cpp under Source Files*

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "graphics.h"

//Graphics Class holds all information dealing with graphics for the game

Graphics::Graphics() {
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(640, 480, 0, &this->_window, &this->_renderer);
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(this->_window, "Cavestory");
}

Graphics::~Graphics() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(this->_window);
}
```

*main.cpp under Source Files*

```
//Main.cpp - Entry point of program

#include "graphics.h"
#undef main

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) { 
    Graphics graphics;
    while (true) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please tell me what to play around with in settings/code? Thank you!

PS: I've only been learning C++ for about a month now, so I'm pretty horrible for now.

Comment: what is EXACTLY Your problem? Always giev error messages, symptoms etc. Impossible to help with "this dont work"

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot do that simply (and in *standard* C++11, there is no graphics; check by reading *carefully* [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)). You need some *external* library, like [Qt](http://qt.io/), [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/), etc... (and you'll find also [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) specific libraries, perhaps [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)...)

Most [GUI toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) libraries have some [*event loop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) which is often provided by some function of that graphical library. You need to dive into their documentation to find which. Qt has [lots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html) of tutorials. Its even loop is started with [`QApplication::exec`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec).

Both Qt & SFML (and many other [widget libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits), but not all of them) are cross-platform (source code using them can be recompiled for Linux, for MacOSX, for Windows). Since my computer runs Linux, I prefer them.

PS. Notice that [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) is a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (on the command line) with some [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor). Such a combination is called an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). You could also be interested in using some (vendor neutral or [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)) [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)).

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answer. To tell the true, question is very bad

Answer (score 0):

He appears to be adding directories (in very small text). Setting up a project is shown here [Setting up SDL 2 on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/msvsnet2010u/index.php)